# How to configure Rails console to work with foreign languages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, utf-8, character-encoding

Need to do some testing in foreign languages in the console.

I configured iTerm to display the following Chinese text: `巧克力`, but when I try to paste it into the Rails console or IRB it displays incorrectly (as 5 characters).

How to configure Rails console to display the text correctly?

Rails 3.0.7
Ruby 1.9.2p290
OSX 10.7.4
rbenv